# OpenShift Pro: Failed to list appliedclusterresourcequotas/v1 (-1)

Tags: openshift

I now have three webapps migrated to OpenShift Pro.

When I leave them running overnight and return in the morning, several error windows have appeared.

Any ideas what is causing this?

[image: Web Console]

Comment: Do the web apps continue running successfully despite the errors?

Comment: It can mean two things. The first is that the web sockets connection for the session was dropped or was a transient network issue. Refreshing the web page should fix it. The second is that your login session timed out. In that case refreshing the page would likely ask you to login again. So the question is if refreshing the page everything appears to work okay again.

Comment: The web apps appear to all be ok, the same deployments are running and the error messages disappear when the page is refreshed...

Answer (score 0):

It can mean two things.

- The first is that the web sockets connection for the session was dropped or was a transient network issue. Refreshing the web page should fix it.
- The second is that your login session timed out. In that case refreshing the page would likely ask you to login again. So the question is if refreshing the page everything appears to work okay again.

(I copied  Graham Dumpleton's answer from comments)